# Encoding problems when sending data via sockets

Tags: c#, objective-c, sockets, networking

I am trying to send data to a UDP server, and I have some problems. I don't receive data after sending. Then I tried a network logger. And I can see when i use `NSUTF8Stringencoding` it show on network log but when I use `NSASCIIEncoding` it doesn't not send.

I would really like some help. I am using `CocaoAsyncUDPSocket`. If anynone could help receive data again, that would be really cool.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *ipString = @"192.168.0.116:7777";
NSArray *splitArray = [ipString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

NSString *ip = [splitArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *port = [splitArray objectAtIndex:1];

NSArray *ipArray = [ip componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
char ipNumber1 = [self chr:[[ipArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue]];
char ipNumber2 = [self chr:[[ipArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue]];
char ipNumber3 = [self chr:[[ipArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue]];
char ipNumber4 = [self chr:[[ipArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue]];

char portByte1 = [self chr:[port intValue] & 0xFF];
char portByte2 = [self chr:[port intValue] >> 8 & 0xFF];
NSString *packetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SAMP%c%c%c%c%c%cp4150", ipNumber1, ipNumber2, ipNumber3, ipNumber4, portByte1, portByte2];

GCDAsyncUdpSocket *socket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
NSError *err = nil;
NSData *data = [packetString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
[socket sendData:data toHost:ip port:[port intValue] withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
NSLog(@"%@", packetString);
```

This one never gets called:

```
-(void)udpSocket:(GCDAsyncUdpSocket *)sock didReceiveData:(NSData *)data fromAddress:(NSData *)address withFilterContext:(id)filterContext; {

    NSLog(@"Received data");
}
```

Here is the same functionality written in C# http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism/Csharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString` is for a sequence of Unicode characters, and cannot used as a container for
an arbitrary byte sequence which you have here.

You better build the message in a byte buffer first and convert that directly to
`NSData`:

```
unsigned char buffer[20]; // Choose a size that is large enough for your messages
memcpy(&buffer[0], "SAMP", 4);
buffer[4] = [[ipArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
buffer[5] = [[ipArray objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
buffer[6] = [[ipArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
buffer[7] = [[ipArray objectAtIndex:3] intValue];
buffer[8] = [port intValue] & 0xFF;
buffer[9] = [port intValue] >> 8 & 0xFF;
memcpy(&buffer[10], "p4150", 5);
int messageSize = 15;
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:buffer length:messageSize];
```

Comment: Thanks alot that code worked! Is it possible for you to explain the code, so I can learn from it?

Comment: @user3287428: Which part do you not understand?

Comment: Nevermind. I understand it now. although I could use some help on reading the bytes I get back. How do I read the bytes? Here is how the bytes are layed out: http://wiki.sa-mp.com/wiki/Query_Mechanism#Response_from_i The one response from i

Comment: @user3287428: For example: `const unsigned char *response = [data bytes]; int password = response[11];` .

Comment: Hi again. Now, I have some problems. How do I retrieve a letter from it? Like if byte ten is "p" how to get it into a NSString?